Control PreComp's Sublayers within Composition
Creatives
Creating a reusable template for an animated mindmap's layers.
Subject: Puppeting Title Precomp Sublayers
Task: Prepared the Mind-Map's titles to be structured in a recognisable order for the expression/script to manipulate to the dictation of the Voiceover (VO).
Instructions: The Title precomp, which has been manually divided into each of its masked layers, will need to be controlled each layer at a time.  This precomp is at it's native scale of 25576x14386px for a 1080 main composition. The precomp's layers are in sequential order. The VO with markers imbeded to trigger the revealing (opacity) of each title.
Context: Discovered 'Master Properties' and the pickwip expression from one comp to another.  I also need to connect the VO's markers to the 'title' precomp's opacity which would then control each of it's sublayers one after the other.

Please read tags' summary descriptions before applying them.  This question has nothing to do with the Puppet configuration management system, so I have removed the "puppet" tag.
